# Java dynamic programming “Climbing Stairs”, do not understand the logic

Tags: java, algorithm, dynamic-programming, fibonacci

Question is: You are climbing a stair case. It takes n steps to reach to the top.
Each time you can either climb 1 or 2 steps. In how many distinct ways can you climb to the top?

And I saw a java code which is correct, but I don't understand the logic. Can anyone explain it to me? What's a,b,c stand of?

```
public int climbStairs(int n) {

    if (n<2) return 1;

    int a = 1;
    int b = 1;
    int c = 1;

    for (int i=2; i<=n; i++){
        c = b;
        b = a + b;
        a = c;
    }
    return b;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The recursive formula is

```
f(n) = f(n-1) + f(n-2)
f(0) = f(1) = 1
```

---

Translated to `a, b, c` in the code

```
if (n<2) return 1;

int a = 1;
int b = 1;
int c = 1;
```

The above defines `f(0) = f(1) = 1` and below calculates `f(n) = f(n-1) + f(n-2)` for `n >= 2`

```
for (int i=2; i<=n; i++){
    c = b;     // f(i-1) is temporary saved in c
    b = a + b; // f(i-2) + f(i-1) is saved in b
    a = c;     // f(i-1) is saved in a for the next iteration
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The code itself is basically a fibonacci-number generator.

```
int a = 1;
int b = 1;
int c = 1;

for (int i=2; i<=n; i++){
    c = b;
    b = a + b;
    a = c;
}
```

creates the `n`th fibonacci-number, starting with 1 for `n = 0`.

So the more important question:
How does the number of possible ways correspond to the fibonacci-row?

For `n = 0` and `n = 1`, the answer is pretty simple: there's exactly one way: don't move (0), take a single step (1). For any other `n`, we can use a recursive approach: there are two ways to reach step `n`: take a short step from `n - 1` or a long step from `n - 2`. Which is the same as the fibonacci-sequence: `fib(n + 2) = fib(n + 1) + fib(n)`.